# Is the Elasticsearch sorting applied after or before index analysis (scan)?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, lucene

I am using Elasticsearch 6.2, and I have some queries that analyze a massive amount of documents. I am sorting to one field inside the index. Elasticsearch examines 10.000 documents (default configuration value) and then returns them paginated.

I tried to read the documentation, but I cannot find any information if the database applies the sorting before or after the analysis process of the documents from the index.

In other words, the sort is applied directly during the index analysis or the documents are sorted once analyzed? If the last option is correct, which kind of sort applies Elasticsearch during the scan?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you searching on text field?

Comment: Nope. Mainly in `keyword` fields.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorting, aggregations, and access to field values in scripts requires
>   a different data access pattern. Instead of looking up the term and
>   finding documents, we need to be able to look up the document and find
>   the terms that it has in a field.

This quote from the Elasticsearch reference documentation implies to me, that sorting is happening on the non-analyzed level, but I've also decided to double check and do some tests on it.

In the Elasticsearch we have capabilities to do sorting on non-analyzed fields - e.g. *keyword*. Those fields are using doc-values to do sorting and after the test I could say that **it's using pre-analyzed values** to do sorting according to the codes representing characters (numbers, uppercase letters, lowercase letters)

It's also possible to do a sorting on *text* fields with some caveat and tuning (e.g. need to enable **fielddata**, since text fields do not support **doc_values**)

In this case the documents are sorted **according to analyzed values**. Of course a lot depends on analyzing pipeline, since it could do various stuff to the text. Also, just as a reminder:

> Fielddata can consume a lot of heap space, especially when loading
>   high cardinality text fields. Once fielddata has been loaded into the
>   heap, it remains there for the lifetime of the segment. Also, loading
>   fielddata is an expensive process which can cause users to experience
>   latency hits. This is why fielddata is disabled by default.